# How to set network intent VLAN in Windows Server using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, networking, android-intent, azure-stack, wac

I was creating an Azure Stack HCI cluster using the Windows Admin Center (following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-stack/hci/deploy/create-cluster) with the Network ATC option) when I lost connectivity to the nodes (i.e. they were only reachable through the console).

After some troubleshooting, I realized that during the *3.2 Deploy host networking settings* step of the *[Clustering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-stack/hci/deploy/create-cluster?tabs=use-network-atc-to-deploy-and-manage-networking-recommended#step-3-clustering)* phase, the Windows Admin Center reconfigured the network interfaces with the specified intents, but without keeping any existing VLAN settings.

In my case, the NICs had been set to use a certain VLAN ID before starting the cluster creation in Windows Admin Center. I did not notice that during this process the wizard never asked for a VLAN ID (not even when setting the management and compute intents), so I proceeded without giving it too much thought. When the Windows Admin Center created the network intents, it reconfigured the NICs without setting a particular VLAN ID (completely ignoring the one that had been previously set), leaving the nodes unreachable.

The Azure Stack HCI OS is based on Windows Server 2022 Core, so it does not have a GUI. I have been trying to figure out what is the PowerShell command to set the VLAN ID at least to the management intent, but all I could find was this guide which only specifies how to create a new intent with a given VLAN ID (instead of setting it to an existing intent): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-stack/hci/manage/manage-network-atc. Also, there are no documentation pages related to the `Set-NetIntent` or `Get-NetIntent` commands used in that article.

So is there a way to set a VLAN ID to an existing network intent, or do I have to delete the intent and create it again with the VLAN (as per the guide above)? Also, assuming that such a command exists, does the Windows Admin Center have an option to set the VLAN ID during the cluster creation or is using PowerShell the only way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out the command by myself after studying the parameters in the [Network ATC article I linked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-stack/hci/manage/manage-network-atc):

```
Set-NetIntent -Name Management -ManagementVLAN <VLAN_ID>
```

Also, I reviewed the cluster creation process using Windows Admin Center and indeed, when using the Network ATC option it never asks for a VLAN ID for the management and compute intents. Apparently the only way to do it - as of today - is using PowerShell.